# Error: No space left on device: (deleted)/dev/zero

Tags: linux, centos7, vps, troubleshooting, virtual-memory

**** Hoster something changed on hypervizor but said, that nothing was changed. The problem is not on the server anymore... ****

[image]Could someone help me to solve the following problem:

If I want to restart the daemon, I have the notification:

```
Error: No space left on device
```

lsof | grep deleted:

```
rewrite-0 11111 11153     nginx  mem       REG               0,96           598535772 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
rewrite-0 11111 11153     nginx  mem       REG               0,96           598535778 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
rewrite-0 11111 11153     nginx  mem       REG               0,96           598535776 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
```

And a lot of other string for php-fpm, mysql..

This is VPS Centos.
Can't find any solution for that.
Would be very appreciate for the help!

#### UPDATED

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop16716p1  200G   11G  181G   6% /
devtmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              3.0G  248K  3.0G   1% /run
tmpfs              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              615M     0  615M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs              615M     0  615M   0% /run/user/0
```

ls -la /dev/zero

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Aug 21 16:21 /dev/zero
```

df -i

```
Filesystem          Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/ploop16716p1 13295616 353527 12942089    3% /
devtmpfs            786432     65   786367    1% /dev
tmpfs               786432      1   786431    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               786432    221   786211    1% /run
tmpfs               786432     10   786422    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs               786432      1   786431    1% /run/user/1000
```

[root@mail ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/file bs=1G count=50

```
50+0 records in
50+0 records out
53687091200 bytes (54 GB) copied, 168.672 s, 318 MB/s
```

[root@mail ~]# du -hs /file

```
51G     /file
```

[root@mail ~]# df -h

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop16716p1  200G   61G  131G  32% /
devtmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              3.0G  252K  3.0G   1% /run
tmpfs              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              615M     0  615M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs              615M     0  615M   0% /run/user/0
```

For any reason:

repquota -a:

```
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/ploop16716p1
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      -- 7523364       0       0         251948     0     0       
nobody    --      20       0       0              5     0     0       
smmsp     --      92       0       0             23     0     0       
rpc       --       4       0       0              2     0     0       
apache    --      16       0       0              4     0     0       
mysql     --  180824       0       0            384     0     0       
named     --      12       0       0              3     0     0       
user      --  236604       0       0           1081     0     0       
clamupdate --  260460       0       0              5     0     0       
dovecot   --       4       0       0              1     0     0       
postfix   --     728       0       0             80     0     0       
vmail     -- 1415436       0       0          14824     0     0       
spamd     --      32       0       0              9     0     0       
nginx     --  775704       0       0          57129     0     0       
amavis    --    4644       0       0             31     0     0       
postgrey  --   10340       0       0              9     0     0       
opendkim  --      40       0       0             10     0     0       
opendmarc --     212       0       0              3     0     0       
redis     --     284       0       0             16     0     0       
ossec     --   29108       0       0           1216     0     0       
ossecr    --     284       0       0              5     0     0       
ossecm    --       4       0       0              1     0     0       
#500      --   97932       0       0           5318     0     0       
#1001     --    7024       0       0            435     0     0       
#984      --     532       0       0            136     0     0       
#501      --   22356       0       0           2645     0     0
```

I've contacted the hosting provider and they tell me, that the problem they can't find, but logs saying:

```
Aug 24 07:43:17 mail yum[17224]: Installed: strace-4.12-6.el7.x86_64
Aug 24 07:53:43 mail clamd[1484]: SelfCheck: Database status OK.
Aug 24 07:55:58 mail systemd-tty-ask-password-agent: Error: No space left on device
Aug 24 07:55:58 mail systemctl: Failed to stop systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path: Unit systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path not loaded.
Aug 24 07:55:58 mail systemctl: Failed to stop systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service: Unit systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service not loaded.
```

And after that restart for daemons is working without any problem.
Any ideas, dear community?

ipcs -a

```
------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

Comment: Do you actually have enough space on `/`? The `/dev/ploop....` indicates a loopback file system on the VPS host and if the hoster overcommited storage, the hosting file system might be full.

Comment: Check if you can create a file. In the situation I mean, you would get a report that you have plenty of space left, but that's your storage quota. The host FS might be full anyway.

Comment: [root@mail ~]# touch /testfiles
[root@mail ~]# ls -la /testfiles 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 23 14:14 /testfiles

Comment: succesfully created

Comment: Also nothing in /var/log/messages or in journalctl

Comment: You can create empty files all day. But can you create files with data in them? This is almost 100% your VPS provider has run out of disk space. OpenVZ VPSes lie about how much disk space they really have available.

Comment: Updated the topic. I can create files without any problem. With dd created file 50G

Comment: OK, i re-read your question. But something important is missing: What gave you the error message?

Comment: When I do: systemctl restart "any-daemon". I have the error message: Error: No space left on device

Comment: Normally when a process has a deleted file open the kernel will present it with ` (deleted)` appended to the name. But in your case you have `(deleted)` in the beginning (without a space). I think that difference will provide a clue. Possibly it didn't actually open `/dev/zero` but rather a path ending with `/dev/zero` in which an intermediate directory has been deleted, unmounted, or is otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Updated the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem soved for now with sysctl parameter: fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 10240

Answer (score 0):

Since everything else people have suggested for you has failed, I'll try a more exotic one -- has your system for some reason run out of semaphores?

If `ipcs -a` shows you a long list, then it might be worthwhile to remove the most obvious ones (like, semaphores existing for a user which only should run some service which has already been stopped) with the `ipcrm` command.

Comment: Everything is emtpy in output

Comment: OK. Well, it was worth a try.